# connect a 2nd router to set-top box

Tags: router

I pretend to connect a router (Thomson TG784n) to other router (TP-Link TL-WR1043ND V2) using a ethernet cable, and connect a set-top box (scientific atlanta KMM 3010) to the TP-Link. Both routers have a wireless network, and the connection between the TP-link and the set-top box is by ethernet cable.
[image: diagram]

update: TV decoder is really a set-top box

I've follow this How-To's:

- [How to Connect Two Routers](http://www.wikihow.com/Connect-Two-Routers)
- [Can I connect two routers to the same network with the same network name?](https://support.bluesound.com/hc/en-us/articles/204524383-Can-I-connect-two-routers-to-the-same-network-with-the-same-network-name-)
- [Como ligar um router ao router Thomson da Meo via Cabo](http://pplware.sapo.pt/microsoft/windows/como-ligar-um-router-ao-router-thomson-meo/)

I can create a wireless network, however the TV sometimes freeze. How can i solve this?

Comment: You haven't provided enough details... I'm assuming that you connecting TV by W-Fi? In what situations TV freezes? Randomly? Have you tried to update TV firmware?

Comment: Thank´s for your comments. I´m connecting the set-to box to the Tp link by ethernet cable.  The TV freezes randomly. It´s not a TV problem, is a router configuration.

Comment: The most important thing that we need to know here is WHY? - What circumstances lead up to this ? What does this configuration fix? Let me know.

Comment: I have the Thomson router in one room connected by ethernet to the set-top box located in the living room, where the wireless signal is low. I also have a Tp link router available.I pretend to have a strong wireless signal in the living room, so i pretend to use the TP link router to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After 10 router resets and a help*-desk* from tp-link it's working. I had to disable the IGMP Proxy in the Network - Lan menu of the 2nd router (TL-WR1043ND V2).